# Algebraic Geometry - maximal ideal in a ring of polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A = K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ be a ring of polynomials in $n$ variables over a field $K$, and $I$ a maximal ideal of $A$. Show that:

a) If $V(I) \neq \emptyset$, then $V(I)$ is a set that contains a single element.

b) Conclude from part a) (without using any version of nullstellesatz) that if $K$ is Algebraically closed, then every maximal ideal of $A$ is of the form $(x_1 - a_1, ..., x_n - a_n)$ , for $a_1, ..., a_n \in K$.

**attempt**: item a) ok, i got it. But I don't know how to use item a) to prove item b) without using some version of Nullstellensatz.

Comment: have you discussed the theory of Jacobson rings ?

Comment: (I removed my answer since I saw you are not allowed any form of the Nullstellensatz). If you want to use the result from a) then you need $V(I)\neq\emptyset$ and that is exactly what the weak Nullstellensatz says. If you are not allowed to use this then you can't use $V(I)\neq\emptyset$ (any way you get it is either using the weak Nullstellensatz or an alternative proof of it) and so you can't apply the result from a).     Where did this question come from?